# When Installing Ubuntu 20.04 on Win10 machine get "starting sector number exceeds the msdos-partition-table-imposed maximum of

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, windows-10

Ubuntu 20.04 fails to install in a dual boot environment.  Searched other boards and all are very old answers.  My BIOS is set for both Legacy + UEFI. Answers I have found are given from the point that you are already on a Linux box.  I have not found any answer given with Windows installed as the first OS from the OEM. Searched many U Tube vids on how to install.  Straight forward but none address the error I have. My disk is a 1 TB SSD and after shrinking it I can get up to 400 GB for Linux.  AMD Threadripper with 16 cores and 64 GB RAM

The full error message is `starting sector number exceeds 4296015872 the msdos-partition-table-imposed maximum of 4294967295`

TIA, Steve

Comment: I would set your bios to UEFI only and try the Ubuntu install again. Windows will almost certainly be UEFI. I could be wrong but I don’t think you can boot a single disk in either mode. The Legacy or UEFI option probably allows the system disk to boot UEFI and an external usb device to boot Legacy. Whatever the case forcing UEFI may solve your problem

Comment: Did as you suggested.  It made no difference. Same error message.  So I really do not know why U-tube vids show it can be done but it is not working.  I have just settled with Linux running Virtual Box.  Less hassle. But thanks for your comment anyway.